# how to add a function to make sure that a specific user has a been deaf already

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

okay, first of all, I made this simple code, but am not sure how to add a function to make sure that a specific user has no deafen already... **this code made using discord.js v12**

***It simply gives a specific user a deafen while the user at voice chat.***

```js
    if(!message.member.hasPermission('DEAFEN_MEMBERS')) return;

    const user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    // if(user...
      
      if(!user.voice.channel) return message.channel.send(`**:rolling_eyes: This member isn't in a voicechannel**`)
            user.voice.setDeaf(true);
              message.channel.send(`**✅ | Done deafen ${user}.**`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`VoiceState.deaf`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=deaf)

```js
if (!user.voice.channel)
 return message.channel.send(
  `**:rolling_eyes: This member isn't in a voicechannel**`
 );

if (user.voice.deaf)
 return message.channel.send('This user is already deafened');

user.voice.setDeaf(true);
```

Comment: I didn't think that its simple as this, btw thank you very much.
have a nice day.

Comment: You too! Glad I could help :)